# How to create custom phtml to PDF and attach in email at admin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email

I am already created Custom email from admin panel with attachment of sample pdf file, 
But now i want to create **.phtml file to .pdf file** & which is **attach in my custom email.**

Answer (score 1):

Step 1)
Download **TCPDF** library from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf
and place at magento2.0/lib/internal/**TCPDF**

Step 2) Rename **tcpdf.php** to **TCPDF.php**

Step 3) Open TCPDF.php and change class name to class **TCPDF_TCPDF**

Step 4) Create Controller magento2.0/app/code/Namespace/Module_Name/Controller/Generatepdf/**createpdf.php**

```
< ? php

namespace Namespace\Module_Name\Controller\Generatepdf;

use TCPDF_TCPDF;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Createpdf extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {

    public function execute() {
 $baseDir = DirectoryList::MEDIA;

$tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information

        $tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

        $tcpdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');

        $tcpdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');

        $tcpdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');

        $tcpdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');


// set default header data

        $Header_title = 'Sample PDF';

        $tcpdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE . $Header_title, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0, 64, 255), array(0, 64, 128));

        $tcpdf->setFooterData(array(0, 64, 0), array(0, 64, 128));


// set header and footer fonts

        $tcpdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

        $tcpdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


// set default monospaced font

        $tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


// set margins

        $tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

        $tcpdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

        $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


// set auto page breaks

        $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor

        $tcpdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// set some language-dependent strings (optional)

        if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {

            require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');

            $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($l);

        }


// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode

        $tcpdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

//your htmls here

$html = **For PDF file Write Your HTML Code here** ;

// set some language dependent data:

        $lg = Array();

        $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';


        $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($lg);


// set font

//dejavusans & freesans For Indian Rupees symbol

        $tcpdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

        // remove default header/footer

//$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

        $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


        $tcpdf->AddPage();


        $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


        $tcpdf->lastPage();



//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

        $this->logger->debug('report_per_route');

        $filename = $baseurl . '/Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';

        $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'F');




   }

}


? >

Step 5) After click Call your controller in your phtml file


< a href="< ? php 
**echo $block->getUrl('namespace_modulename/generatepdf/createpdf');** ? > " > 
< button class="action-default scalable action-secondary" title=" < ? php echo __('Create Pdf') ? > " type="button" >< span >< span >< span >< ? php echo __('Create Pdf') ?></ span></ span ></ span ></ button >
</ a>
```

Comment: It is working fine upto Magento2.1.9. But not working with Magento2.2 version. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Hi @Ajay , Did u get any solution for Magento 2.2 version?

Answer (score 0):

You can user some pdf library library like `tcpdf` to achieve your task. Here some pre defined function available like [writehtml()](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/) which convert whole html into pdf.

Comment: I am gone through link for Use TCPDF in Magento 2 http://www.ashrafulabedein.com/use-tcpdf-magento/   but i didn't get exactly this code can be in view file or in controller. so please help me generate phtml to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library which convert HTLM to PDF :

http://www.html2pdf.fr/

But you need to create a custom module for your feature.

Comment: worst plugin ever

Comment: Please comment why it is worst. It is useful for common task.

Comment: html5 and css3 doesn't work

Comment: Indeed it is an old library, but for basic usage, I think it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\YouBlockName::class)
            ->setTemplate("VendoreName_ModuleName::YourFileName.phtml");

        $pdfData = [];
        $pdfData["body_data"] = $block->toHtml();
        $config = [
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font_size' => 10,
            'default_font' => "dejavusans",
            'margin_left' => 1.5,
            'margin_right' => 1.5,
            'margin_top' => 1.5,
            'margin_bottom' => 1.5,
            'allow_charset_conversion' => true,
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'showBarcodeNumbers' => false,
            'tempDir' => $this->dir->getPath('var'),
        ];
        $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
        $pdf->WriteHTML(html_entity_decode($pdfData["body_data"]));
        $outputData = $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D'); // D , F , S
    }

    /**
     * Initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->config = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->config;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->config, null, true);

        $this->ucdn = $path . 'Ucdn.php';

        // require_once $this->ucdn;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ucdn, null, true);

        $this->defaultCss = $path . 'Css/DefaultCss.php';

        // require_once $this->defaultCss;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->defaultCss, null, true);

        $this->sizeConvertor = $path . 'SizeConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->sizeConvertor;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->sizeConvertor, null, true);

        $this->colorconverter = $path . 'Color/ColorConverter.php';

        // require_once $this->colorconverter;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->colorconverter, null, true);

        $this->gradient = $path . 'Gradient.php';

        // require_once $this->gradient;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->gradient, null, true);

        $this->tableOfContents = $path . 'TableOfContents.php';

        // require_once $this->tableOfContents;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tableOfContents, null, true);

        $this->cache = $path . 'Cache.php';

        // require_once $this->cache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cache, null, true);

        $this->fontCache = $path . 'Fonts/FontCache.php';

        // require_once $this->fontCache;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontCache, null, true);

        $this->fontsFileFinder = $path . 'Fonts/FontFileFinder.php';

        // require_once $this->fontsFileFinder;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontsFileFinder, null, true);

        $this->cssManager = $path . 'CssManager.php';

        // require_once $this->cssManager;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->cssManager, null, true);

        $this->otl = $path . 'Otl.php';

        // require_once $this->otl;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->otl, null, true);

        $this->form = $path . 'Form.php';

        // require_once $this->form;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->form, null, true);

        $this->hyphenator = $path . 'Hyphenator.php';

        // require_once $this->hyphenator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->hyphenator, null, true);

        $this->tag = $path . 'Tag.php';

        // require_once $this->tag;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->tag, null, true);

        $this->namedcolors = $path . 'Color/NamedColors.php';

        // require_once $this->namedcolors;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->namedcolors, null, true);

        $this->pageformat = $path . 'PageFormat.php';

        // require_once $this->pageformat;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pageformat, null, true);

        $this->fontVariables = $path . 'Config/FontVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->fontVariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->fontVariables, null, true);

        $this->textvars = $path . 'Css/TextVars.php';

        // require_once $this->textvars;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->textvars, null, true);

        $this->border = $path . 'Css/Border.php';

        // require_once $this->border;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->border, null, true);

        $this->logcontext = $path . 'Log/Context.php';

        // require_once $this->logcontext;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->logcontext, null, true);

        $this->ttfontfile = $path . 'TTFontFile.php';

        // require_once $this->ttfontfile;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->ttfontfile, null, true);

        $this->destination = $path . 'Output/Destination.php';

        // require_once $this->destination;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->destination, null, true);

        $this->mpdfexception = $path . 'MpdfException.php';

        // require_once $this->mpdfexception;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->mpdfexception, null, true);

        $this->metricsgenerator = $path . 'Fonts/MetricsGenerator.php';

        // require_once $this->metricsgenerator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->metricsgenerator, null, true);

        $this->GlyphOperator = $path . 'Fonts/GlyphOperator.php';

        // require_once $this->GlyphOperator;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->GlyphOperator, null, true);

        $this->barcode = $path . 'Barcode.php';

        // require_once $this->barcode;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->barcode, null, true);

    }

}
```

> Here get your phtml file content using **createBlock()** and store data into **$pdfData["body_data"]** variable.

**Note: MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command which placed into the vendor directory.**